# Mouse Not Working Properly

Tags: mouse

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 but for some reason the mouse isn't working properly. Problems I'm experiencing are: left button on the mouse doesn't work, the cursor doesn't highlight anything, as well, the right side will not do a double click function. Doesn't seem to bring up the mouse menu to "go back" as well, "go forward" options. In order to make things work, I have to use the Enter key, and arrow keys.

Comment: What type of computer are you using? I'm using a Lenovo Z560, and I've had problems like this before.

Comment: VTC as not reproducible. OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years to answer comments essentially making it an abandoned question. Ubuntu 11.10 hit EOL on May 9, 2013.